# Return Matrix Field block number

Tags: matrix

Just wondering if there's a way to return the matrix block number during the loop?

For example:

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrixField %}
  {% if block.type == "quote" %}
    <blockquote class="quote{{GET_BLOCK_NUMBER}}">
      <p>{{ block.quote }}</p>
    </blockquote>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Might return something like this:

```
<blockquote class="quote1">
  <p>Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p>
</blockquote>
<blockquote class="quote2">
  <p>Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p>
</blockquote>
<blockquote class="quote3">
  <p>Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p>
</blockquote>
```

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes that's possible, all Twig loops have a [`loop` variable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable):

> `loop.index` - The current iteration of the loop. (1 indexed)
>   `loop.index0` - The current iteration of the loop. (0 indexed)

**Example:**

```twig
{% for block in entry.myMatrixField %}
  {% if block.type == "quote" %}
    <blockquote class="quote{{ loop.index }}">
      <p>{{ block.quote }}</p>
    </blockquote>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```